# Failure in adding examples of new and existing intents on IBM Watson's conversation tool

Tags: watson-conversation, watson

I have been creating intents using Ibm Watson. But recently, Watson shows a crossed circular icon anytime I try to add examples to the intents I've created. Watson says you have 25,000 examples for intents in both Lite and premium versions of the conversation tool. Being that I can still create entities, which have lesser limits in comparison to examples, I don't think I should be having this problem. I need help please.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be hitting the service limits for your account.

On Watson Conversation the lite plan covers

```
Lite
10,000 API Calls per Month*
Up to 5 Workspaces
Up to 25 Intents
Up to 25 Entities
*POST /message method calls only

Standard
Unlimited API queries per month
Up to 20 Workspaces
Up to 2000 Intents
Up to 1000 Entities
Shared Public Cloud
*POST /message method calls only
```

This limit also applies if you have multiple service instances running on your account.

Comment: Thank you @ReeceMed. I had three workspaces, but I have filtered them down to just one. Also I deleted some practice Intents and entities I previously had. I am able to create intents but yet unable to add examples.

Comment: I do believe there is also a limit of 25,000 examples contained on the lite plan, however I will ask internally if this is the case

Comment: I definitely haven't used that much examples becuase 25, 000 is a lot. However, does it get renewed every month ?

Comment: @JoshuaGiwa it will renew each month like the API calls, however, it does seem unlikely you would use that many examples, are you able to provide a view of how many examples you have? Or export your workspace json

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I resolved the problem. It was a silly mistake being that I had to title the examples before adding them. However, I was doing the reverse. Thank you for your commitment to my issue.